# Infragistics Excel Import Loadoptions

Tags: vb.net, excel, parsing, uri, infragistics

there are two Errors came up on the Load-Method for loading Excel-Sheets through Infragistics Components.

**First:**

- **The specified stream or file does not contain a valid workbook.
  Parametername: fileName**

This ist because the Excel-Workbook is corrupt. But how can I load the Workbook without validating if its corrupt or not?

**Second:**

- **Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed**

This is because there are Hyperlinks in Worksheets. How can I remove them before Loading?

My Code:

```
'stuff...
Dim file as String = "test.xls"
xls = New Workbook()
xls = Workbook.Load(file)
'stuff...
```

The Page from Infragistics is not very helpful: http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Documents.Excel.v12.2~Infragistics.Documents.Excel.Workbook~Load(Stream).html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, Thank you for the Response! Answer ist following:

**First Question was:**

- **The specified stream or file does not contain a valid workbook. Parametername: fileName**

> Answer:
>
> - There is no Option to Load a corrupt Workbook into your App without validating the Workbook or something like this. You need to handle this
>     Errormessage and the User must choose another, valid File!

**Second Question was:**

- **Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed**

> Answer:
>
> - There were mailto-Links in the Worksheets. Normally this is not a Problem for Infragistics. But the mailto Links were broken like this:
>
>   ```
>   mailto:eric@ domain.com
>   ```
> - You see: A space bar in that mailto-Link - so the Link is
>     corrupt. The Invalid Uri came up because of this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be using this method for the wrong purpose, I've not got experience using 'Infragistics' however looking at the link you provided this looks like a method for opening a web based stream as a Workbook object.

The error message you are receiving is saying that it cannot read the `file` argument you are calling `Workbook.Load` with. My guess is that this method expects a URL (e.g. www.stackoverflow.com), where as you are providing it with 'test.xls'

Based on the code you provided it looks like you are simply looking to open a workbook you have on your own machine, to do this you can use the `Workbooks.Open` method, for example:

```
xls = Workbook.Open(ThisWorkbook.path & "\test.xls")
```

This will open the workbook named "test.xls", from the same folder as the file containing your macro, and assign it to `xls`.

Comment: There is no `Open` Member on `Workbook`

Comment: The Load method is the correct method and when passing a string it is loading the file: http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Documents.Excel.v12.2~Infragistics.Documents.Excel.Workbook~Load(String).html

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to the first question is that you aren't able to load a corrupted workbook as the Excel Engine can't understand the file.  It is possible that if you open the file in Excel it might be able to repair it and then you might be able to open it with the excel engine.

I believe that hyperlinks are supported by the Infragistics Excel engine and you should provide Infragistics with a sample of a valid excel file that has issues loading because of hyperlinks in the file for them to look into.